# Monero and JSON-RPC

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, json-rpc

I got a few questions but got nowhere to ask them so I think this is a good place.

I want to use an external daemon host to not download the blockchain.
Can I at the same time use the JSON-RPC to my `localhost` or at all??

I've been having issues starting the `monero-wallet-cli` since when I supply `--rpc-bind-port 18082` it instead of starting gives me a help with commands and in there I don't see the `--rpc-bind-port` command.

I'm using UBUNTU latest, and latest Monero wallet from their website..

Comment: You should also post this question as an issue on monero's GitHub page. Might have better luck there.

Answer (score 3):

Do you by any chance confuse `monero-wallet-rpc` with `monero-wallet-cli`?

---

`monero-wallet-rpc` connects to a wallet and provides RPC functionality.

`monero-wallet-rpc` has the option you are searching for: `--rpc-bind-port`:

`--rpc-bind-port arg            Sets bind port for server
    --rpc-bind-ip arg (=127.0.0.1) Specify IP to bind RPC server`

---

Hint:

Maybe you should have posted your question on https://monero.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with `--daemon-host` and `--trusted-daemon/--untrusted daemon`. I don't think it is possible to change wallet rpc port manually.